# FieldAttributeEnum, DataTypeEnum: VB/ADODB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, adodb

I'm converting some VB code to C#/.Net. I need equivalents for the following:

> RecordSet
>   FieldAttributeEnum
>   DataTypeEnum

I think `RecordSet` might be replaced with `DataSet`, but I don't know about the other two. Any ideas?

Some example code:

```
Private Function CreateRecordsetFromDataGrid(ByVal DGV As DataGridView) As Recordset
    Dim rs As New Recordset
    'Create columns in ADODB.Recordset
    Dim FieldAttr As FieldAttributeEnum
    FieldAttr = FieldAttributeEnum.adFldIsNullable Or
                FieldAttributeEnum.adFldUpdatable
    For Each iColumn As DataGridViewColumn In DGV.Columns
        'only add Visible columns
        If iColumn.Visible = True Then
            Dim FieldType As DataTypeEnum
            'select dataType
            If iColumn.ValueType Is GetType(Boolean) Then
                FieldType = DataTypeEnum.adBoolean
```

Comment: Does this help you ? http://www.vbtonet.com/legacy-data-access-to-net/adodb-sql/

Comment: They are ADO types, an earlier COM based technology to use databases.  There is no direct translation to .NET, you have to rewrite the code.  Otherwise entirely unrelated to the language you use.  Or continue to use ADO, it works fine in C# as well, add ADODB from the Add Reference > Assemblies > Extensions list.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer: That link shows using DbType for DataEnumType, and there seems to be equivalents, e.g. DataTypeEnum.adBoolean -> DbType.Boolean.
There is no mention of FieldAttribeEnum, though, but at least this is part way there.

Comment: RecordSet converts to DataSet partially, but not fully. RecordSet relies on a connection, unlike a DataSet. Also a DataSet can also process multiple tables at once, unlike a RecordSet.

Comment: Have a look at the `DataColumn` class as it may have some more of the info you're looking for. AllowDBNull, DataType etc.

Comment: Yes, `DataColumn` looks usable. It doesn't have an "updatable" field, but perhaps that's because its always updatable.

Comment: You want to completely refactor/rewrite this. With the move to .Net, ADO became ADO.Net, with all new types that are similar to, but not exactly 1:1 replacements for, the old ADO library.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer: As has been pointed out, there is no way to directly translate, but the link you suggested and the use of `DataColumn` are useful, so you could post that as an answer.

Comment: @AlLelopath thanks for the comment. I feel my comments were only suggestions and couldn't constitute a complete answer. Maybe once you have a full solution you can post that as an acceptable answer?

Comment: Such ethics. Much wow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out, it is not a direct translation. As @David notes, `DataSet` can have more than 1 table, but I need only one. Also note the link given by @AndrewMortimer in the comments, it is helpful. Code looks like this now:

```
private DataTable GetDataTableFromDataGridView(DataGridView dataGridView)
{
    const string TABLE_NAME = "SheetOne";

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable(TABLE_NAME));

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn iColumn in dataGridView.Columns)
    {
        // add only visible columns
        if (iColumn.Visible == true)
        {
            DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn();
            dataColumn.AllowDBNull = true;
```

Comment: You'll have to keep in mind that this post does not answer the question.  Something like "There is no equivalent, you'll have to completely rewrite it" would perhaps be more accurate but is not going to be very helpful nor appreciated by anybody that googles the question some day.